# How to set a "variable" that can be commited on git in linux?

Tags: linux, git, bash

I have a hardcoded the name of a folder for versions in a .sh script , so when I want to switch to other version I have to change it manually in all the files , what is the best way to set a "variable" that can be commited on git ? 
Now in my files it is something like : program/1.0.0/ 
And I want to make it like : program/$latest_version
I tried with a symbolic link , I don't know pretty much bash , and I cannot take the value :
ln -s 1.0.0/ latest_version

Comment: What do you mean by commiting a variable? Why does  it not help to achieve your goal to commit a little piece of code which just intialises the variable?

Comment: Please explain more clearly the exact environment and situation you have so people can understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Yunnosch  by commiting a variable I wan't to say that I am able to push it on git , so when you pull the project variable it will be already set.

Comment: Ok. Now please answer the second question form my comment; keeping in mind that you can only push the content of files, but neither process status nor environment variable values directly. The currently available answer agrees, but you did not accept it. So.....  what is needed differently?

Comment: It is possible to push a symbolic link (my "Variable")  , and I would like to keep it as "clean" as possible on outside (less files)  , so I want to know if it is anything else over there that works like that  , or how can I use the symbolic link in my script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a file called `conf.dist.sh` to your repository, like this:

```
FOLDER_NAME="default-folder-name"
```

On top of your script source that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "conf.sh"
```

When you clone the repository, copy `conf.dist.sh` to `conf.sh`, change to folder name according to your needs but *don't* add `conf.sh` to git to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to use the symbolic link  like this: 
    (ln -s 1.0.0/ latest_version)//creation of link
    program/$(readlink latest_version)// using it in script